# How to list the categories of the current store?

Tags: magento, categories, magento-1.5, product

I have a site which have 2 store views. I want a page to list the categories of the current store and when I click on a category it should display all of the products in that category in a list.

Any who can give some idea about this?

Comment: Is there any one who can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That page already exists by default in Magento. It is probably a link in the page footer as "Site Map", or you can reach it directly by typing the URL of the store followed by `/catalog/seo_sitemap/category`